# html button anchor display block

Tags: html, css

Anchor tag doesnt resize automatically depending on the content, see the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/XmnnY/

I know I can use display inline or display inline-block, but I need that the anchor tag automatically sets its width depending of the inner html size (which is text in this case).

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use float:left/right (if you can) and clear:both on following item, or

use inline-block but remove all whitespaces and returns, because inline-block displays all the spaces in the inner HTML

```
<a href="#" style="display:block;float:left;">
    <img src="button.gif" />
</a>
<div style="clear:both">next element</div>
```

is ok, but also

```
<a href="#" style="display:inline-block;"><img src="button.gif" /></a>
```

Note I have removed all returns and spaces inside the a tag

Float:
http://jsfiddle.net/XmnnY/18/
InlineBlock:
http://jsfiddle.net/XmnnY/16/

Answer (score 3):

Since you gave it a `display: block` style, it will assume the full available width.

Either set a hard `width`, or change the display to `inline-block`.

There is no reason why changing it to `inline-block` might break anything else you need, if it does, either change the width dynamically using JS, or fix the problem it creates.

Comment: inline-block creates this odd spacing that I can't get rid off